# python: matplotlib: plot datetime against values with changing colour

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a list of datetime elements agains some values so that I could watch the behaviour of an experiment with time. I'm able to do so correctly but I can't make the colour of the plot vary according to a list of colour names. There are some discontinuities in the measurement curve, so I use np.nan not to plot anything.

My script could be simplified as:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time = [datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 12, 45, 35), datetime.datetime(1900,1, 1, 12, 45, 40), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 12, 45, 45), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 12, 45, 50), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 12, 45, 55), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 12, 46), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 12, 46, 5), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 12, 46, 10)]
values = [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 3,np.nan, 5, 6]
colors = ['r', 'r', 'y', np.nan, 'y', np.nan, 'g', 'y']

# data plotting

plt.figure()
plt.plot(time, values, c=colors)
plt.show()
```

Can anybody help me with this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't pass a list of colors to `plot()` (from the docs: *"color or c: any matplotlib color"*). See http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html for examples on how to create a line plot with changing colors.